# How to install software library again and have both two?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have installed tesseract-ocr with apt-get

and now

i want to get svn code, make some changes in it and compile it on my own and install again.

I want first instance remain, and give a different name to newly installing instance. But installation, make procedures and linux logic requires put .h files into general folders like "/usr/include" without specific folders.

So what is the easiest path to install another instance of the same program. Thanks

Comment: To the close voter: I'd argue this *is* a programming question about the use of build systems and autoconf, since compilation from SVN source implies development activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install it with a different **prefix**. When the program publisher had the foresight to use an autoconf-like configure script, you can simply use the --prefix option:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=`pwd`/install
```

to install the library in the install subdirectory. For CMake and other "improved" build systems, read their documentation, many do provide some switch for that.

Comment: thanks for argument and valuable response, i am going to try.